# How to pass values from ajax to php using GET

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this script in ajax and is used to pass the value chosen by the user in the combo box to php. This also handles the submit button.

**AJAX:**

```
<script>    
function loadXMLDoc(usertype) {
    var value = $('#usertype').val();
    var page='checksignup.php?usertype='+usertype;
    document.location.href=page;
}


$( "#register_Chairperson" ).submit(function( event ) {
  var usertype = $('#usertype').val();
  alert(usertype);
  loadXMLDoc(usertype);
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

And I'm using this php code to get the value pass by ajax. But my problem is that nothing happens. My address became only like this: `http://localhost/civil-engineering-dept/checksignup.php?usertype=1`. It did not continue in checking for the form for signing up. What do you think is the problem?

**PHP:**

```
$user = $_GET["usertype"];
```

Comment: Here its listed how http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ OR http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @sravis According to your given link (api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) it will request or load from the server but in my case I think it is different. I'm not requesting or loading from the server I would want to pass only the `usertype` variable to php.

Comment: provide the action="..." value from your form.

Answer (score 1):

> And I'm using this php code to get the value pass by ajax.

That's not ajax, it looks like an attempt to load the XML in the browser window. To actually do that, change `document` to `window` and lose the `href`.

```
window.location=page;
```

To actually use ajax, you'd use [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) or [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (since you're trying to do a GET); something like this:

```
$.get(page)
    .done(function(xml) {
        // Worked, do something with the XML
    })
    .fail(function() {
        // Failed, show/handle the error
    });
```

Comment: Sir in my case I would only want to pass the parameter `usertype` in PHP. Sorry Sir if I cannot explain it clearly because I'm newbie here in this area.

Comment: @Harvey: You're passing it correctly (provided the usertype is just a number, as you've shown it; if it were text, you'd need `encodeURIComponent`). It should be available from `$_GET`.

Comment: Yes Sir, that's a number. Okay I'll better check my code again. Thanks Sir!

Answer (score 0):

try this

> $user = $_REQUEST["usertype"];